# get attribute value from html code in java

Tags: java

i have HTML string value and i want to get one attribute(id) value from that html String value
can u help me how to do it??

```
String msHTMLFile = "<ABBR class='HighlightClass' id='highlight40001' style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: yellow\" >Fetal/Neonatal Morbidity and Mortality</ABBR>";
```

result should come - highlight40001;

Comment: what is this? Servlet, JSP, Applet? give more relevant information

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regular expression pattern:

```
\bid='([^']*)'
```

And then extract the string captured by group 1. This is not foolproof; using regex to parse HTML never is. You can try to complicate the regex to make it more flexible. Or you can just use a HTML parser. I recommend the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Also not so clean, but this should work for you.
You can treat it as xml and parse it using JAXB:

ABBR.java:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public class ABBR
{
    @XmlAttribute public String id;
}
```

Main.java:

```
[..]
String msHTMLFile = "<ABBR class='HighlightClass' id='highlight40001' style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: yellow\" >Fetal/Neonatal Morbidity and Mortality</ABBR>";
ABBR obj = JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader(msHTMLFile), ABBR.class);
System.out.println(obj.id);
[..]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're lucky and your HTML source produces XML-compliant HTML, JAXB or other XML parsers will do fine with it.  A lot of people aren't writing particularly well-formed HTML (unclosed tags, etc), though some of my coworkers have gotten good results parsing HTML with HotSAX: http://sourceforge.net/projects/hotsax/